# Android - How to add custom word prediction? (Pinyin Like)

Tags: android, dictionary, prediction, android-keypad, search-suggestion

I develop an app in local language (Khmer) and I want to provide word predictions (En -> KH) for users when they type Roman on EditText it would suggest words in Khmer.

I have check personal dictionary, but it's not available anymore in Android 8. The Text Shortcuts is not what I'm looking for.

This is sample of my word: 'សួស្តី' - ['Sur', 'Soursdey', 'Sursdey'].

Note:

1. I don't want to develop a new keyword, just add a list of words
   mapping.
2. Is it possible to show suggestion only on my app?

[image: Sample Picture]

Comment: There isn't really a feature for what you want.  You can use inputMethodManager.displayCompletions to pass a list of custom completions to the keyboard.  But there's no promise the keyboard will use them, and if it does it will probably be instead of all other possible completions (turning off any existing ones).

Comment: @GabeSechan thank you, I will look into inputMethodManager class. But do you have any sample of other use case that similar to mine?